# VBS Script issue

Tags: vbscript

I'm attempting my first coding for a program to open a set of programs upon launch

I've got this script for one program but I'm getting a VBS compilation error

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\servicecentser\Run\scguiw32.exe" -

express:dvla.servicecenter.fs.fujitsu.com.12680""")
Set objShell = Nothing

objwindow.document.getElementByID("username").value = "EXAMPLE"
objwindow.document.getElementByID("password").value = "EXAMPLE"
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? What does it say? What have you tried?

Comment: Get it when i try to launch the script i have tried what the user below has said im unable to get that to work

Comment: I mean at what line do you get the error, and what does it say? I guess it has to do with the quotes.

Comment: sorry yeah line 3 char 77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes in string literals have to be escaped by doubling; line breaks in literals are not allowed; no param list () when calling a sub; try:

objShell.Run """C:...\scguiw32.exe"" ""-express:dvla.servicecenter.fs.fujitsu.com.12680"""

Comment: managed to get it working using this took me ages to notice i made a mistake in spelling center